# mysql sum() and double result Using Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql

**I have table tb_orders**

| id_order | lot | rekanan | no_order | pec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5555 | 1 | GOZNAK | 390 | y |
| 6666 | 1 | KOMSCO | 391 | y |

**I have another table tb_pengambilans_detail**

| id | id_order | tanggal | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 137 | 5555 | 2021-01-05 09:36:16 | 100000 |
| 136 | 6666 | 2021-01-05 09:35:57 | 100000 |
| 94 | 6666 | 2020-12-15 15:00:47 | 100000 |
| 138 | 5555 | 2021-01-05 09:37:51 | 100000 |

**table tb_lini_pengambilans_detail**

| id | id_order | tanggal | deret5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 6666 | 2020-12-08 09:26:36 | 30000 |
| 39 | 5555 | 2020-12-08 09:31:49 | 10000 |
| 40 | 6666 | 2020-12-14 07:55:36 | 80000 |
| 41 | 6666 | 2020-12-14 07:57:34 | 20000 |

**table tb_produksi_cutpacks_detail**

| id | tanggal | id_order | hcts | unfit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 2021-01-04 13:02:10 | 5555 | 5000 | 0 |
| 32 | 2021-01-04 14:10:05 | 5555 | 0 | 10000 |
| 34 | 2021-01-04 15:11:57 | 5555 | 0 | 2000 |
| 35 | 2021-01-04 15:14:10 | 6666 | 9000 | 0 |

**table tb_lini_produksi_cutpacks_detail**

| id | tanggal | id_order | xbaik | xderet5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 2021-01-04 14:52:38 | 5555 | 4000 | 1000 |
| 18 | 2021-01-04 14:53:21 | 6666 | 8000 | 0 |
| 19 | 2021-01-04 14:53:36 | 6666 | 0 | 2000 |
| 21 | 2021-01-04 14:57:41 | 5555 | 0 | 15000 |

I have done separately, all the results are correct and not double

```
SELECT a.rekanan,
    SUM(COALESCE(b.jumlah,0)) AS `pengambilan`
 FROM tb_orders a
LEFT JOIN tb_pengambilans_detail b USING(id_order)
WHERE a.pec='y'
GROUP BY a.rekanan
```

**Result**

| rekanan | pengambilan |
| --- | --- |
| GOZNAX | 200000 |
| KOMSCO | 200000 |

```
SELECT a.rekanan,
  SUM(COALESCE(c.unfit + c.hcts,0)) AS prod_hcts
FROM tb_orders a
LEFT JOIN tb_produksi_cutpacks_detail c USING(id_order)
WHERE a.pec='y'
GROUP BY a.rekanan
```

**Result**

| rekanan | prod_hcts |
| --- | --- |
| GOZNAX | 17000 |
| KOMSCO | 9000 |

```
SELECT a.rekanan,
  SUM(COALESCE(d.deret5 ,0)) AS `pengambilanlini`
FROM tb_orders a
LEFT JOIN tb_lini_pengambilans_detail d USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN tb_lini_produksi_cutpacks_detail e USING(id_order)
WHERE a.pec='y'
GROUP BY a.rekanan
```

**Result**

| rekanan | pengambilanlini |
| --- | --- |
| GOZNAX | 20000 |
| KOMSCO | 260000 |

And Last

```
SELECT a.rekanan,
  SUM(COALESCE(e.xbaik + e.xderet5 ,0)) AS prod_hctslini
FROM tb_orders a
LEFT JOIN tb_lini_produksi_cutpacks_detail e USING(id_order)
WHERE a.pec='y'
GROUP BY a.rekanan
```

**result**

| rekanan | prod_hctslini |
| --- | --- |
| GOZNAX | 20000 |
| KOMSCO | 10000 |

after I was sure about everything then I joined all the tables, and the results were all double ...

```
SELECT a.rekanan,
SUM(COALESCE(b.jumlah,0)) AS `pengambilan`,
SUM(COALESCE(c.unfit + c.hcts,0)) AS prod_hcts,
SUM(COALESCE(d.deret5 ,0)) AS `pengambilanlini`,
SUM(COALESCE(e.xbaik + e.xderet5 ,0)) AS prod_hctslini
FROM tb_orders a
LEFT JOIN tb_pengambilans_detail b USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN tb_produksi_cutpacks_detail c USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN tb_lini_pengambilans_detail d USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN tb_lini_produksi_cutpacks_detail e USING(id_order)
WHERE a.pec='y'
GROUP BY a.rekanan
```

**Result**

| rekanan | pengambilan | prod_hcts | pengambilanlini | prod_hctslini |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GOZNAX | 1200000 | 68000 | 120000 | 120000 |
| KOMSCO | 1200000 | 108000 | 520000 | 60000 |

What is the solution so that the SQL result is not double ..
please tell me so that the problem can be resolved ..
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

----  Actual single SQL solution is ---------------

```
 SELECT a.rekanan,
SUM(COALESCE(b.jumlah,0)) AS `pengambilan`,
SUM(COALESCE(c.unfit + c.hcts,0)) AS prod_hcts,
SUM(COALESCE(d.deret5 ,0)) AS `pengambilanlini`,
SUM(COALESCE(e.xbaik + e.xderet5 ,0)) AS prod_hctslini
FROM tb_orders a
LEFT JOIN (select id_order ,SUM(jumlah) jumlah from  tb_pengambilans_detail group by id_order)  b USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN (select id_order ,SUM(unfit) unfit ,SUM(hcts) hcts  from  tb_produksi_cutpacks_detail group by id_order)  c  USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN  (select id_order ,SUM(deret5) deret5  from  tb_lini_pengambilans_detail group by id_order) d USING(id_order)
LEFT JOIN  (select id_order ,SUM(xbaik) xbaik , sum(xderet5) xderet5  from  tb_lini_produksi_cutpacks_detail group by id_order) e USING(id_order)
WHERE a.pec='y'
GROUP BY a.rekanan
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer ..
my problem is finally over ..
its working..regards

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never voted ... how do I vote?

Comment: No problem ...just click answer's left side up arrow

Comment: oh ok .. sorry ..
I have voted for you..
Once again, thank you